# Reading from file returns 2 dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x

```
data = [line.strip('\n') for line in file3]
# print(data)
data2 = [line.split(',') for line in data]
data_dictionary = {t[0]:t[1] for t in data2}
print(data_dictionary)
```

So I'm reading content from a file under the assumption that there is no whitespace at the beginning of each line and not blank lines anywhere.

when I read this file I first strip the newline character and the split the data by a ',' because that is what the data in the file is separated by. but when I make the dictionary it returns two dictionaries instead of one it's doing that for other files where I use this procedure. how do I fix this?

Comment: What does "two dictionaries" mean? What does that look like?